# How Elasticache nodes save data

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, memcached, amazon-elasticache

suppose i have create a cache cluster with 4 nodes. Now I'm having 1 single configuration url for elastic cache cluster. & when ever i hit config url...it choose an random node nd store my data & these nodes are in-synch.

Now my question is that ...suppose i stored 5GB data then it will be stored on my both the nodes? It means in my 4 nodes 20GB space will be occupied which is illogical.

Can somebody explain how this works & is there any solution to get rid of this problem ?

I wanted to know how it store and serve data actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the caching engine and configuration you are using with Elasticache. For example, if you are using Redis with replication, that would consume 10G (5 on the master and 5 on the slave). If you are using Memcached without replication, data would be stored only on the node you hit, so you would use ~1.25G per node.

Comment: I'm using memcached engine & having 2 nodes into the cluster. As an endpoint i'm using the the configuration endpoint, behind that auto discovery works...now how i will come to know that my data is stored on which node ? Will Elastic cache replicate my data on both the nodes ?

Comment: As per this link :-

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/AutoDiscovery.HowAutoDiscoveryWorks.html

data individually stored on the nodes & at the configuration end point on the basis of some hashing algo based on the key..it generates the node end point to fetch the same data. 

It concludes that elasticache(memcached) nodes does't replicate the data. Please correct if i'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, Memcached does not replicate data by default, you should not care about what data is cached on what node, as cache nodes should be disposable. If you need persistence and/or master-slave replication, take a look at Redis. If you need multi-master replication, check other cache/data grid engines such as Infinispan, Hazelcast, Coherence, etc... (that is not to say redis or memcached can not be a data grid, i'm being * very * simplistic in this comment)